# Tie breaking using Rank function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, vba

I have a student's result sheet, where I calculated the total number the student has gained. Next, I want to rank them according to the grand total, and wherever it duplicates, the student getting more number in maths(E9:E58) will be given priority,

How to accomplish it?

I have my grand total from U9 to U58, and maths score in d9 to d58.

I have used this formula:

```
=Rank(u9,u9:u58,1)
```

I am stuck in how to use the if condition within the rank function.

Please help.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Depending on how your data is set up, you might be able to use the `RANK` worksheet function, along with an `IF` or something similar to invoke the tiebreaker algorithm.  Post back with what you have tried if you run into problems.  Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I hope this edit works, please do help me.

Answer (score 1):

In that sort of situation, one method of adjusting is to use the `SUMPRODUCT` function.  You will need to adapt my example to your data ranges.  In the example below, you don't need columns E:F.  They are only there so you can better see how the adjustment is accomplished.

### Adjustment Function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2=Totals)*(B2>Maths))
```

### adj Rank Function

```
D2: =RANK(C2,Totals,1)+SUMPRODUCT((C2=Totals)*(B2>Maths))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, Total score is in `Column U` and Math's score is in `Column E,` you can use Ron's solution as:

```
=RANK(U9,U$9:U$58)+SUMPRODUCT((U$9:U$58=U9)*(E$9:E$58<E9))
```

Enter above formula in 9th row of the column where you want Rank to be displayed and then drag/copy it down till 58th row.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of arithmetic approach. I would add a column called adjusted total.

```
AdjTotal = Total + (Maths Score / Max possible Maths Score) * 0.9
```

Then use this Adjusted score column to rank.

The adjustment will add a fraction under 1 to the total and will help break the tie when there is one. Since the adjustment will never be more than 0.9 it will not affect ranks when there is no tie.

Assuming Max score for Maths is 100, use this

```
V9 = U9 + D9/100*0.9
```

Copy V2 down till V59

```
W9 = RANK(V9, V$9:V$59, 1)
```

Copy W9 down.

Comment: What are you signifying by V2, U2 and D2 @eshwar

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by running the usual `RANK()` method and then adding in the `RANK()` method on a filtered set that matches the other rows tied with the current row. Since the `RANK()` call for the tiebreak will start at one you will need to subtract one to compensate.

The end result ends up looking like:

```
=RANK(U9, U$9:U$58, 1) + RANK(D9, FILTER(D$9:D$58, U$9:U$58=U9)) - 1
```